# Passing a struct to a dynamically loaded dll

Tags: c++, dll, struct

I have a dynamically loaded dll that has functions called on it, and i would like to pass it a struct. It is dynamically loaded as i do not know which version of the dll i will be using untill runtime.

Firstly, should i pass by value or reference?

Secondly, where do I declare this struct so it is available to both the dll and its caller (i assume it has to be available to both).

If i declare it in the same dll that accepts it as a parameter, then surly any potential user of the dll will have to statically link against the dll so it has access to the struct declaration, and this is what i originally wanted to avoid.

Comment: I would have thought that the struct declaration would be in a header file?

Comment: You are basically asking "How to ensure my code crashes quickest when the wrong DLL version gets loaded?"  By value is best, it imbalances the stack pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, should i pass by value or reference?

That depends, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference).

> Secondly, where do I declare this struct so it is available to both the dll and its caller

You declare it in a header file that both use. The struct is declared at compile-time, no linking against any library is needed for that.

Comment: Thanks Georg, could you elaborate on this header i declare the struct in please? would it be the same header that declares the c interface for my dll? Do i just create a standalone header file which i include in both projects? As both projects are c++, do i put the declaration in a extern "C" directive? please forgive my ignorant questions.

Comment: @pingu: Where to put the struct depends a bit on your project - but it should go in a header of the host; the header where you define the interface would be one possibility. The struct needs no `extern "C"`. As both sides are C++, depending on your setup, you may only need `extern "C"` for one function. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/431578/168225) for a question on such a setup.