# Implementing an interface in dll which is declared in main app - C++

Tags: c++, dll, interface, implementation

I have a main app which has an interface(abstract class) and this interface need to have implementations both in main app and an external dll.
I will be using the pointer to this interface to access the methods, so i will be assigning pointer to address of the any one of the implementations based on some condition.

How can this be achieved?

I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431533/c-dynamically-loading-classes-from-dlls) in stack overflow where the answer marked as solution says

An interface in main app

```
class IModule
{
    public:
    virtual ~IModule(); // <= important!
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};
```

can be implemented in main app

```
class ActualModule: public IModule
{
    /* implementation */
};
```

And can export a function from dll to return pointer to implementation in dll

```
__declspec (dllexport) IModule* CreateModule()
{
    // call the constructor of the actual implementation
    IModule * module = new ActualModule();
    // return the created function
    return module;
}
```

How will dll come to know that something like **IModule** exists?

Can i mark the **IModule** as *extern* and use in dll?

Answer (score 1):

'How will dll come to know that something like IModule exists?'

Because the dll code will include the header file where IModule is declared. Header files are the way to share declarations between different source files. Dlls make no difference to this, and there is no need to mark IModule as extern.

BTW I would do this

```
virtual ~IModule() {} // <= important!
```

Comment: Okay, is it good if i use two copies of same header file. One in main app and one in dll.I just want to compile the two projects independantly. Apart from sync problems, what else would come in picture.

Comment: Well, don't use two copies.  Just have one, tell the compiler where to find it.  You've got enough versioning problems as is.